# Add Element to ArrayList in a HashMap by returning the ArrayList and assigning a value to it

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

## Introduction

We want to search in a `Map` if it contains a specific `singer`. If so then we will add a `disk` to the `list of disks` that belong to the `singer`. If the `singer` doesn't exist then we add the `singer` to the `Map` with an empty `ArrayList`.

The structure of the map is the following :

```
Map<Singer,List<Disk>> diskMap = new HashMap<Singer, List<Disk>>();
```

The **key** is a `Singer` and the **values** are of type `List<Disk>`.

The code is working correctly. I didn't understand the last part of the code:

```
discography = diskMap.get(singer);
discography.add(disk);
```

- When we use `discography.add(disk);` to add a disk. Will it be updated in the Map?
- Is it similar to diskMap.get(singer).add(disk)?
- If it is updated correctly? How does it work in memory?

---

## Source code

```
public void addDisk(Disk disk){
    Singer singer = disk.getSinger();
    List<Disk> discography = null;
    if(diskMap.get(singer) == null){
        diskMap.put(singer, new ArrayList<Disk>());
    }

    discography = diskMap.get(singer);
    discography.add(disk);
    }
```

Comment: Are you on Java 8? If so, `diskMap.computeIfAbsent(singer, x -> new ArrayList<>())` solves this in one line.

Comment: 1) it will update your map value    2)  diskMap.get(singer).add(disk) and discography.add(disk); are both same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When we use discography.add(disk); to add a disk. Will it be updated in the Map?
>   => Yes.
>
> Is it similar to diskMap.get(singer).add(disk)?
>   => Yes.
>
> If it is updated correctly? How does it work in memory?

discography = diskMap.get(singer);

This assign the discography var to the same object (same list) as the map entry.

Both point to the same memory object (same reference). If you add or remove element to discography it will affect the list in the map too

Comment: yes I check the size of the List in the map and it was increasing. Really interesting. I was lost with the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> When we use discography.add(disk); to add a disk. Will it be updated in the Map?

Map value for given key points to list. Calling `map.get` does not copy value for given key.

> Is it similar to diskMap.get(singer).add(disk)?

Yes.

> If it is updated correctly? How does it work in memory?

Yes. In memory:

- `map.get` find and return list for given key. If no values then return `null`. Internally `HashMap` use `EntrySet` to store Key-Value pairs called `Map.Entry`.
- `list.add` add element to list. Java lists are mutable so there will not be any copying.

Comment: Yes. In Java we use only references for object types. For primitives we use values.

Comment: Have a look at this topic. There is a lot of informations that can enlight you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value